# Add custom properties to SharePoint 2007 Survey

Tags: sharepoint-2007, survey

I would like to extend the survey list template and add 2 more properties. The place to modify these properties is the Survey General Settings page (/_layouts/ListGeneralSettings.aspx?List=).
Can someone tell me how to add these kind of properties to survey list in SharePoint or any other possible places to store these properties?

Regards,
Voicu Seiche.